# Should BroadcastReceiver be declared inside activities?

Tags: android, design-patterns, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm wondering what's the better cleaner design approach to handle **BroadcastReceiver** creation between those two:

1. Declaring directly a **BroadcastReceiver** in an Activity/Fragment and overriding onReceived method there.
2. Creating another custom receiver class in a package "receiver", that extends the **BroadcastReceiver** class and override onReceive. Then, you instantiate that custom receiver class in your Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Basically you want to know whether to use an anonymous class or declare the class properly? Both options will lead to the same result, and the answer would be purely opinion based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 types of Broadcast Receivers

1)Dynamic Broadcast Receiver that is registered inside activity

2)Static Broadcast Receiver that is registered or declared inside Manifest file with Receiver tag with specific action(when to fire the Receiver)

Uses:Eg say receive message

1) Dynamic Broadcast Receiver is used to receive the Broadcast intent mainly to refresh the message sent through send Broadcast method.

2)Static Broadcast Receiver is used to receive the message.Here the Registered Receiver with SMS receive action will receive the message and later it sent to  activity

At last It depends on developer which one to use,when to use based on requirement

Comment: Then I think i've been misusing it because I used it to start a intent-service or service in the onReceived. Is it bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

There is no cleaner approach, it depends on how you Code.

Following the DRY principle, I only extend a `BroadcastReceiver` as soon as I notice I'll need them in different Activites.